# How can I call a method for these vectors inside a loop?

Tags: scala

I am trying to do exercise one of Summary Two in Atomic Scala.

Why does the following code run fine

```
val chars = Vector('z', 'a', 'b')
val ints = Vector(0, 3, 7)
val strs = Vector("these", "are", "vectors")

println(chars.sorted)
println(ints.sorted)
println(strs.sorted)
```

but the next script below throws me an error `.\Summary2.scala:7: error: No implicit Ordering defined for Any.
        println(v.sorted)`

```
val chars = Vector('z', 'a', 'b')
val ints = Vector(0, 3, 7)
val strs = Vector("these", "are", "vectors")

for (v <- Vector(chars, ints, strs)){
    println(v.sorted)
}
```

By the way, I can iterate through the vector of vectors if I just want to print each vector. `sorted` just doesn't work in the loop.

```
val chars:Vector[Char] = Vector('z', 'a', 'b')
val ints:Vector[Int] = Vector(0, 3, 7)
val strs:Vector[String] = Vector("these", "are", "vectors")

for (v <- Vector(chars, ints, strs)){
    println(v)
    // println(v.sorted)
}
```

I get this output

```
Vector(z, a, b)
Vector(0, 3, 7)
Vector(these, are, vectors)
```

It's pretty basic and the official book solution is the first script, but it's really annoying me that the second script doesn't work.

Comment: The type of `v` must be consistent. It can't have a different type for each iteration, therefore the compiler gives it the common super-type `Any`, which doesn't have a `sorted` method.

Comment: So, Scala just doesn't let me use a for loop to do this. I have to use the first script? If the answer is that it is possible but why and how is complicated, that's fine. That would be a helpful answer to me at least. I can accept that and go on to the next lesson in the Scala book.

Answer (score 2):

Scala is a strongly typed language so at compile time the compiler must know what the type of everything is in order to create a correct program.

Let us see what scala considers the type of your vectors to be

```
scala> val chars = Vector('z', 'a', 'b')
chars: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Char] = Vector(z, a, b)

scala> val strs = Vector("these", "are", "vectors")
strs: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[String] = Vector(these, are, vectors)

scala> val ints = Vector(0, 3, 7)
ints: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(0, 3, 7)

scala> val vs = Vector(chars, ints, strs)
vs: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Any]] = Vector(Vector(z, a, b), Vector(0, 3, 7), Vector(these, are, vectors))
```

As you can see the vector you've created to iterate over has type

```
scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Any]
```

In order to be sortable we must be able to define `<, <=, >, >=` and as you can see from the `Any` class definition, this type only implements `!=, ==`

Thus, we are unable to sort an object with type `Any` because with only the equality and not equality operators, we do not understand what a correct ordering is.

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.5/scala/Any.html

Comment: I'm not trying to sort `Vector(chars, ints, strs)`, the vector of vectors. I just want to sort each vector in the vector of vectors. 
`for (v <- Vector(chars, ints, strs)){
 println(v)
}
` works.

Comment: @vivian you can iterate the vector of vectors. And you print them and do anything that you can do with a `Vector[Any]`, but `sort` it is not something you can do with that. The moment you created a **vector** of **vectors** of different types, you lost all the type information of the inner vectors.

Comment: This answer is misleading because the problem is not the lack of comparison operators on the `Any` type. The actual problem is that `sorted` takes an `implicit` parameter of type `Ordering[T]` and there is no `implicit val` of type `Ordering[Any]` in scope. This is a much harder problem to fix!

Answer (score 0):

This problem relates to the way that `sorted` is implemented, because `sorted`  actually takes a parameter to say how the data should be sorted:

```
def sorted[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]) = ???
```

The `ord` value tells the sorting algorithm the correct order for values of type `T`. But this is an `implicit` parameter, meaning that it will be automatically supplied by the compiler if it can see a suitable `implicit val` in scope.

By default there are appropriate values available for sorting standard types:

```
implicit val orderChar: Ordering[Char] = ???
implicit val orderInt: Ordering[Int] = ??
implicit val orderString: Ordering[String] = ??
```

This means that the individual calls to `sorted` are OK for the different `Vector`s.

When you put the different `Vectors` into an enclosing `Vector` the type of this is `Vector[Vector[Any]]` because `Any` is the common super-type of  `Char`, `Int`, and `String`. Unfortunately there is no suitable value for `ord`

```
implicit val orderAny: Ordering[Any] // DOES NOT EXIST
```

This, in turn, means that `Vector[Any].sorted` fails with the error

> No implicit Ordering defined for Any

Comment: Isn't there a way to specify in scala that the type of the elements in a Vector has to have an implicit conversion such as `Ordering[T]`? I'm surprised if this is not possible

Comment: I don't think so, because the compiler finds the `implicit` parameter using the *compile-time* type of the expression, not the run-time type. But I'm not an expert in this area so I am hoping that someone will show that I am wrong!